# use of "po" to get data from server response in console log

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, po

i know this is very basic question that i am gonna ask but i need to ask how can i access data which is dictionary that is getting from server.

here is my response

```
JSON: {
message = "The email must be a valid email address.";}
```

[image]

now i want to do "po" in console log so what to write after in po statement

Thanks

Comment: What is the dataType of response

Comment: Its `po response`? Put break point at the response object also

Comment: bur how can i access only value having inside of "message" key ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need type

```
po yourResponseAsDictionary["message"]
```

**UPDATED**

Sorry I was thinking you already converted it.

If you are not using anything like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) or [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to parse your json data then you can do just the following.
But I would recommend to use some lib to convert response directly to your model

```
let yourResponseFromNetwork = "{ \"country_code\" : \"+9\", \"user_id\" : 123456}"
if let data = yourResponseFromNetwork.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    do {
        if let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] {
            let countryCode = dic["country_code"]
            let userId = dic["user_id"]
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error occurred")
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me same for given response

Comment: SUCCESS: {
    userResult =     (
                {
            "country_code" = "+9";
            "created_at" = "2017-12-08 10:19:05";
            dob = "";
            email = “sdf@sdf.com”;
            gender = Male;
            "is_social" = 0;
            isuserverified = 1;
            password = “sfds”;
            "phone_no" = 997234268;
            "profile_pic" = "12342”;
            "updated_at" = "2017-12-08 10:19:40";
            "user_id" = 16;
            username = sdf;
        }
    );
}

Comment: how can i get value of  keys of "user_id" or  "country_code" etc

Comment: No bro... i want to know how to access those dat a in swift which is coming from server side.... can u guide me how can i do it.

Comment: @BhaumikJoshi Not sure get the point, you mean how to send GET request and receive response ?

Comment: no no..i already done calling of POST request now i get response of it okay and also i show u my response in above comment...till now everything is perfect but now how can i access each value from that response got me now?

Comment: instead of for example printing country code "print(dic["country_code"])" just get it let countryCode = dic["country_code"], or for user id, let userId = dic["user_id"]

Comment: I've changed answer, is it what you need?

Comment: you are just near to my point but not exactly see first of teel me how can i add server response to local dictionary ? so once i add response in local dictionary ll goto the next step got me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161264/discussion-between-mihatel-and-bhaumik-joshi).